# How to import a model as a shape key?

Tags: shape-keys

I want to make changes to a model on Zbrush then bring it back as a shape key on Blender. I won't be adding any geometry just changing the shape.

EDIT: I tried what Mr Zak said but seems like there's something that changes when I export from Zbrush. If I import the basis model into Zbrush and then export it without making changes and use it as the basis it does work.

What should I change on zbrush?

Here's the file with modifiers deleted and some other things I removed. It also has the other model already imported from Zbrush.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sse481vepjp43f/Capn%20B.blend?dl=0

Comment: It should work with using shape keys and *[Join As Shapes](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys.html#shape-keys-panel)* operator in Specials menu.

Comment: Just tried and the mesh totally explodes. I tried removing all modifiers, clicking on "keep vertex order" but nope. What could it be?

Comment: It seems that something still changes with model. What format file do you use for transfer ? You could upload your file with imported model / part of model and add info about export settings.

Comment: @MrZak I attached the file to the original post.

Comment: The base mesh has doubles which can be removed if using dedicated operator. Of course the vertex count won't match after that, but anyway there shouldn't be any doubles in mesh which is equal to another one. It's hard to say what's causing that, probably you might consider sculpting inside Blender to avoid file transfer (still this might not be the option).